# Generate razor syntax in C# class and send to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a class which is called Ratings and has 5 different ratings (1=poor .. 5 = excellent).  I also have a model (Review) which has 10 questions and each uses the ratings class.  Now in the View I have a forEach for each of these properties in the Review class so the code is somewhat cut an paste.  Rather than duplicating the code and just changing a property on them what I would like to do is create a method in the Ratings class which generates the razor syntax, if this is at all possible.

Sample on how it is now and what I would like to do is below.

Current View (only displaying 2 properties:

```
<tr>
    <td class="control-label col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewModel.SpeakerReview, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
    </td>
    @foreach (var rating in ratingModel.RatingList)
    {
        <td class="col-md-1">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReviewModel.SpeakerReview, rating.RatingId)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="control-label col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewModel.AvHandoutsApplicable, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
    </td>
    @foreach (var rating in ratingModel.RatingList)
    {
        <td class="col-md-1">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReviewModel.AvHandoutsApplicable, rating.RatingId)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

How I would like it to look:

View:

```
<tr>
    <td class="control-label col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewModel.SpeakerReview, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
    </td>
    @ReviewModel.BuildRatingList(ratingModel, ReviewModel.SpeakerReview);
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="control-label col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewModel.AvHandoutsApplicable, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
    </td>
    @ReviewModel.BuildRatingList(ratingModel, ReviewModel.AvHandoutsApplicable);
</tr>
```

Class:

```
public static string BuildRatingList(Rating ratingModel, object reviewItem)
{
    string RtnVal = "";
    foreach (var rating in ratingModel.RatingList)
    {
        RtnVal = "<td class='col-md-1'>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => " + reviewItem + ", rating.RatingId)</td>";
    }
    return RtnVal;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use partial views? https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/partial.html

Comment: Struggling trying to pass/read the object to the Partial view and read it. For example, how to pass and read " model.ReviewModel.SpeakerReview",

Comment: In simple case it will be just `@Html.Partial("SpeakerReviewPartial", Model.ReviewModel.SpeakerReview)`

Comment: I did get that far but had issues in the partial view.  Somewhat of a newbie to this.

Comment: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m3-views&mode=live&clip=6&course=mvc4-building maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thx for the link, I did look @ this in the past.  My issue here seems to be the partial views pass models where I am passing it an object.  for example:  1) @Html.Partial("_ReviewRating", Model.ReviewModel.SpeakerReview)   2) @Html.Partial("_ReviewRating", Model.ReviewModel.AvHandoutsApplicable)    in the partial view, need to figure out how to reference the particular property passed.

Comment: can you update your question with your example?

Comment: Im wondering if this post should be deleted, or update everything as we are going down the path of Partial Views vs what the original subject is.

Comment: If partial views seem to answer your need you probably want to accept this answer and create another question with particular partial-view issues you are having, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do almost exactly what you are asking by plugging in extra [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) module from NUGET, I think you are better off using plain [partial views](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/partial.html) or [View Components](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html), e.g. component:

```
namespace ViewComponentSample.ViewComponents
{
    public class PriorityList : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ToDoContext db;

        public PriorityList(ToDoContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
            return View(items);
        }
        private Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            return db.ToDo
                     .Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone && x.Priority <= maxPriority)
                     .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

and view:

```
@using ViewComponentSample.Models
@using ViewComponentSample.ViewComponents
@model IEnumerable<TodoItem>

<h2>ToDo nameof</h2>

<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(PriorityList), 
                      new { maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vittore, going with the Partial View.